# CorePlot / iOS 7.1 / XCode 5.1 After update to XCode 5.1 build fails

Tags: ios, xcode, build, core-plot

I have updated to XCode 5.1 and iOS 7.1 on my device (because my customer required me to). After the update, building fails with a bunch of errors related to core plot:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/michi/Documents/MedSafe/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/michi/Documents/MedSafe/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a (3 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_CPTDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
>         -[MRGewichtKurveViewController configurePlotSpace] in MRGewichtKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRGewichtKurveViewController configureAxes] in MRGewichtKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRGewichtKurveViewController changePlotRange] in MRGewichtKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRBlutdruckKurveViewController configurePlotSpace] in MRBlutdruckKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRBlutdruckKurveViewController configureAxes] in MRBlutdruckKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRBlutdruckKurveViewController changePlotRange] in MRBlutdruckKurveViewController.o
>         -[MRBMIKurveViewController configurePlotSpace] in MRBMIKurveViewController.o
>         ...

and  a lot of others, all involving core plot.

Seems that somehow linking fails or something else while compiling fails. I am a complete noob when it comes to this kind of error :(

Please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using a recent version of Core Plot. Release 1.5.1 contains several changes that were required for Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: First, I download the CorePlot_1.5.1.zip, extract it. I remove the old libCorePlot_CocoaTouch.a and add the new from the zip file. I replace the headers, too. Then I try to build it, it fails, because Xcode does not find elasticGlobalSpace, if I uncomment all lines with `plotSpace.elasticGlobalXRange = YES;`, I can successfully build it. Though I am not sure, if the graph will behave the same, or?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. From the release 1.5 [change log](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/documentation/changelog.markdown): "Removed the elastic global range properties from `CPTXYPlotSpace`. Turning on momentum scrolling now automatically allows elastic ranges, too.".